# Webflux Microservice Error on WebClient Call;

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm trying to get started on Reactive Programming by using Java + Spring + WebFlux.

I've created a Microservice that **produces** a `Mono<Customer>` trough a controller.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<Customer> customerById(@PathVariable String id){
        return customerService.findById(id);
    }
}

public class Customer {

    public Customer(String id, String fullName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotNull(message = "The name must not be null")
    private String fullName;
    private String email;
    private String document;
}
```

And another Microservice that **consumes** this Mono that is a copy of the above class, except for the `Spring Validation` annotations.

On the producer:

```java
//Service Class
public Mono<Customer> findById(String id){
        return Mono.just(new Customer(id, "Joseph"));
    }

//Method on Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/customers")
public class CustomerController {

@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<Customer> customerById(@PathVariable String id){
        return customerService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

When I open the browser on the `Customer Producer` endpoint, I get the following:

```
{
id: "123",
fullName: "Joseph",
email: null,
document: null
}
```

When I invoke the `GET` on the `Customer Consumer` endpoint, I get a `HTTPCode = 500`

Below is the service layer on the `Customer Consumer`

```java
    private String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8060/";

    public Mono<Customer> findById(String id){
        WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();
       return builder               
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri("customers/{id}", id)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Customer.class);
    }
```

I also have tried to remove the `.baseUrl(BASE_URL)` and concating in the `.uri()`, but no success.

The errors I'm getting on the **consumer** side:

```java
2019-12-01 22:21:45.910 ERROR 16788 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [1510eee8]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/v1/customers/123"

java.lang.NullPointerException: null at com.poc.controller.CustomerController.findById(CustomerController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ? HTTP GET "/v1/customers/123" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at com.poc.webportal.controller.CustomerController.findById(CustomerController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
```

**PS**: I know that the WebClient should be on a `bean`, but for instance, I'm just trying to make it work before refactor the code.

Comment: What's the exact URL you used to hit customer endpoint on browser?

and In the error you mentioned, I can see `/v1` in the url path but in the customer consumer, i don't think you've put that in base Url.

Comment: Oh i see, that `/v1` is of `customer` client. right ? Could you also put the code of `CustomerController.java`. there is a null pointer exception on `CustomerController.java:19`

Comment: I added the class declarations on the post with the endpoints mapped so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's embarrassing, but I forgot to Inject the `CustomerService` on the Controller.

So, a `Autowired` fixed the problem..